# jQuery accordion list

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I'd like some tips on optimizing the following code.

I'm a bit concerned that I'm 'polluting the global namespace' by not wrapping it in a function. The commented out `var rotator { init {` came from a JavaScript tutorial but I'm not sure it's the jQuery way? Should I wrap it in `$(function()`... instead?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Promos rotation
var $accordionList = $('.accordion').find('li');

// var rotator = {
//      init: function() {
        var numberOfItems = $accordionList.length;
        var currentItem = 0;

        // Set first item to active
        $accordionList.eq(currentItem).addClass('active').find('.content').slideToggle(800, function() {});
        var infiniateLoop = setInterval(function() {
            if(currentItem == numberOfItems - 1){
                currentItem = 0;
            }
            else {
                currentItem++;
            }

            // Remove active class, if is has it, and close content
            $accordionList.parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active')
                .find('.content').slideToggle(800, function() {
            });

            // Add active class and open content
            $accordionList.eq(currentItem).addClass('active').find('.content').slideToggle(800, function() {
            });

        }, 4000 );

        //$('.accordion li').on('click', function () {
        $accordionList.on('click', function () {
            // Stop rotation
            clearInterval(infiniateLoop);

            var $accordionHead = $(this);

            // Remove active class, if is has it, and close content
            $accordionHead.parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active')
                .find('.content').slideToggle(800, function() {
            });

            // Add active class and open content
            $accordionHead.addClass('active').find('.content').slideToggle(800, function() {
            });
        });
//      }
// };

// rotator.init();

});
```

Comment: _"I'm not sure it's the JQuery way?"_ jQuery way? `$(function(){}) === $(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: you are wrapping it in a function... `$(document.ready(function`...

Comment: Your code as it is does not polute any global namespace, as it's all contained within a function being called by `$(document).ready`. The addition or removal of the `rotator` object does not change this fact. Either way it's wholey contained within a `function`

Comment: Since you wrapped your code in $(document).ready() and you are using the `var` keyword you are surely not polluting the global namespace

Comment: yes but shouldn't I wrap it in another function so it doesn't conflict with other fucntion (yet to be written) that are also in the document.ready ?

Answer (score 3):

To your question ( confirmed by the comments ), you are not polluting the namespace because you are

1. Wrapping already inside `$(document).ready(function() {`
2. Using `var` for every variable.

Furthermore, from what I can see that is left over from `rotator`, it was probably a better approach than what you have now.

From a once over:

- Spelling is important: infiniateLoop -> infiniteLoop
- `slideToggle(800, function() {});` can simply be written as `slideToggle(800);`
- You could use a ternary for increasing `currenItem` : `currentItem = currentItem == numberOfItems - 1 ? 0 : ++currentItem;`
- Please remove commented out code, also please re-indent after taking out `rotator`
- It is considered good practice to have one big var at the start instead of multiple vars:

> ```
> var $accordionList = $('.accordion').find('li'),
>     numberOfItems = $accordionList.length,
>     currentItem = 0;
>
>     // Set first item to active
>   $accordionList.eq(currentItem).addClass('active').find('.content').slideToggle(800);
> ```

- Jshint could not find a single flaw